# Getting Xdebug to work properly with Docker and PhpStorm (it connects)

Tags: php, docker, debugging, phpstorm

UPDATE: Got this working by reducing the `remote_log_level` (first time I had problem with this) and also fixing some missing files in the project (css, js and images) that were causing more calls to nginx and so triggering xdebug.
Thanks [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) for your comments!

I am having some issues on this old CakePHP (2.8.*) project.
I have Docker (php7.1+nginx) and I am using PhpStorm (2019.2.1 Build #PS-192.6262.66, built on August 22, 2019) as an IDE, below is my xdebug.ini (Xdebug v2.9.6) :

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM-into-web
xdebug.remote_log="/application/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_log_level=10
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.sid_%S.pid_%p
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

I am able to get the connection from Xdebug and it initially stops at a breakpoint I have setup at `/application/app/webroot/index.php` (CakePHP code)
[image]

So I can 100% guarantee that the connection is happening and it's right. The issue is that after this Xdebug goes crazy.

To make this a bit clearer, after hitting this initial break point (I have more) nothing more happens in the IDE, the file doesn't change but I am unable to move forwards or into anything.

In a matter of seconds I get the `xdebug.log` file filled with hundreds of these lines:

```
[10] D: Checking whether to break on /application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:346
[10] D: I: Current location: /application/app/webroot/index.php:24
[10] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:346' against location '/application/app/webroot/index.php:24'
[10] D: R: File name length (34) doesn't match with breakpoint (47)
[10] D: Checking whether to break on /application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:302
[10] D: I: Current location: /application/app/webroot/index.php:24
[10] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:302' against location '/application/app/webroot/index.php:24'
[10] D: R: File name length (34) doesn't match with breakpoint (47)
[10] D: Checking whether to break on /application/app/webroot/index.php:109
[10] D: I: Current location: /application/app/webroot/index.php:24
[10] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/application/app/webroot/index.php:109' against location '/application/app/webroot/index.php:24'
[10] D: R: Line number (24) doesn't match with breakpoint (109)
[10] D: Checking whether to break on /application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:346
[10] D: I: Current location: /application/app/webroot/index.php:36
[10] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:346' against location '/application/app/webroot/index.php:36'
[10] D: R: File name length (34) doesn't match with breakpoint (47)
[10] D: Checking whether to break on /application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:302
[10] D: I: Current location: /application/app/webroot/index.php:36
[10] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/application/app/Controller/IndexController.php:302' against location '/application/app/webroot/index.php:36'
[10] D: R: File name length (34) doesn't match with breakpoint (47)
[10] D: Checking whether to break on /application/app/webroot/index.php:109
[10] D: I: Current location: /application/app/webroot/index.php:36
[10] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/application/app/webroot/index.php:109' against location '/application/app/webroot/index.php:36'
[10] D: R: Line number (36) doesn't match with breakpoint (109)
```

In a few seconds the `xdebug.log` is over 20mb, the only way to stop this is to kill the server (using `docker-compose stop`).

So the issue might be with the mappings, which I have done in PhpStorm:
[image]

I normally just add the mappings to the first directory, but after seeing the Xdebug issue I tried adding for other folders but that didn't help.

So my question is, how do I get Xdebug and PhpStorm to correctly map the other files and stop on the breakpoints and not go crazy?

Comment: *"In a matter of seconds I get the xdebug.log file filled with hundreds of these lines:*" -- well, you have configured it to behave like this. Get rid of `xdebug.remote_log_level=10` P.S. There is no need to have separate mapping for `/application` then `/application/app` and then `application/app/Controller` -- children inherit mappings from the parent node.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you, I was just trying to get this to work. It was my first time doing such excess mapping

Comment: @LazyOne regarding the `xdebug.remote_log_level=10`, I've had this kind of debug level on other applications and I never had this amount before

Comment: I have never seen such debug messages before (using default logging level though, never had a need to change it). What Xdebug version do you use? Maybe it's new for upcoming Xdebug v3 (although I think your PHP 7.1 may not supported though)

Comment: 1) Please state your Xdebug and PhpStorm version. 2) Share your Xdebug log for such unsuccessful session, from start to end (but without those extra lines). P.S. Is line 109 the one where it actually stops? I'm asking because it's a bad idea to put breakpoints on multiline statements -- the way how Xdebug/PHP works, the actual line with breakpoint will be somewhere in the middle... That's why you better always put breakpoints on single line/simple statements.

Comment: I've added the details you asked, I lowered the version and it seems to not stall anymore. I am now getting errors on the actual code. The site runs fine if I loaded in the browser (no xdebug running) but when I use the debugger I am getting unknown controller classes.

Comment: Your Xdebug and IDE versions are fine (2018.2 and older will have issues with Xdebug 2.7 and newer). Right now (based on this little to no info) I may only suggest to try and use latest stable 2020.2.2. Currently available info does not allow me to suggest anything more concrete here.