# VSCode hits breakpoints then stops

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

So first of all since October for some reason my previously working Xdebug config for VSCode + Docker stopped working.

I switched over to an Xdebug 3 config to try it out, since 2.9 appears to have stopped working for me. Maybe because of a VSCode or PHP Debug plugin update?

But so far I have been unable to get it working or get it working only half?

VSCode launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/backend": "${workspaceRoot}",
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "resolved_breakpoints": "0",
                "max_data": -1,
                "max_children": -1,
                "max_depth": -1
            },
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

xdebug.ini in Docker (LAMP):

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.mode = debug,profile,trace
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
```

xdebug.log:

My breakpoint is on module.class.php:209

```
[17] Log opened at 2021-12-16 15:36:39.557066
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[17] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.34" protocol_version="1.0" appid="17" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 0
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n max_data -v -1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n max_children -v -1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n max_depth -v -1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t line -f file:///var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php -n 209
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="170001"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- run -i 9
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:10.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209' against location '/var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:10'.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint (51).
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:11.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209' against location '/var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:11'.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint (51).
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:12.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209' against location '/var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:12'.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint (51).
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:15.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209' against location '/var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:15'.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint (51).
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:16.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209' against location '/var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:16'.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint (51).
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="9" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 10
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="10" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[17] Log closed at 2021-12-16 15:36:39.656857

[17] Log opened at 2021-12-16 15:36:39.676911
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[17] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.34" protocol_version="1.0" appid="17" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 0
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n max_data -v -1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n max_children -v -1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n max_depth -v -1
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t line -f file:///var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php -n 209
[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="170002"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] <- run -i 9
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Checking whether to break on /var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Current location: /var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:10.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: I: Matching breakpoint '/var/www/html/backend/classes/data/module.class.php:209' against location '/var/www/html/company_v2_backend/index.php:10'.
[17] [Step Debug] DEBUG: R: File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint (51).
```

... and it's kind of the same from here on out

EDIT:
phpinfo xdebug wizard instructions are:

```
Download xdebug-3.1.2.tgz
Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions. These packages are often called 'php-dev', or 'php-devel', 'automake' and 'autoconf'.
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-3.1.2.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-3.1.2
Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.

Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
Update /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini to have the line:
zend_extension = xdebug
Restart the Apache Webserver
```

Follow these instructions but it doesn't appear to help.

Comment: What does the Xdebug log say, if you create one? A flickering screenshot isn't really all that helpful. See: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log

Comment: Mh I added xdebug.log='/xdebug.log' to the config / is a volume to the  backend but the file remains empty...

Comment: @Florian If it's empty then: 1) file access permissions -- try creating such a file first and make sure that anyone can write to it. Or find another location. 2) Xdebug does not even try to debug, Which is unlikely to be true with your setting and what your GIF shows. Double check your live Xdebug config -- get `xdebug_info()` output captured in the same way as you are trying to debug (CLI or a web page).

Comment: @LazyOne I was trying to use these properties xdebug_info gives me nog errors or anything but the log remains empty...
xdebug.log='xdebug.log'
xdebug.log_level=10

Comment: @Florian `xdebug.log='xdebug.log' ` --- that should be a full path. Make sure it's correct and writeable by anyone. And ensure that the settings are live with `xdebug_info()`. If it's all correct -- then I do not know. You have to have log to be able to see anything. try debugging in CLI environment instead of web -- it may print any errors into standard output if other destination fails... No better ideas from me right now.

Comment: @LazyOne Ah alright I used a absolute path like /var/www/html/backend/xdebug.log and got it working now but the log is >300.000 lines so which one would you like to see. pastebin doesn't really like me pasting that much

Comment: @Florian 1) Address that question to Derick. I'm not using VSCode (PhpStorm user here) so cannot tell how exactly it works (what is the difference that can be causing this). 2) As for the log: clear it, then try to debug -- so it has only 1 session only. The log should be much smaller than 300K lines.

Comment: @Derick log added

Comment: @Derick do you perhaps have some time to look at the logs? I only notice "File name length (41) doesn't match with breakpoint" but am not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 2022/03/01:1300 - Got it working!

We switched from Docker for Windows to running through WSL (See old comments below) and it appeared that I had installed the remote wsl extension in VSCode which I thought was required.

The conclusion is that either Docker got updated and it stopped working with our specific environment or the environment wasn't set up right to begin with (ie. maybe some bug got 'fixed' that it work for us previously).

The configuration I we are using now is very similar:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/php": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\code\\company\\myapp-backend"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

docker compose

```
version: "3.8"

# Services
services:
  # Redis service
  myapp-backend-redis:
    build: ./.docker/redis
    networks:
      - myapp-backend_network
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - 6379
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp-backend-redis

  # Nginx Service
  myapp-backend-nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/php
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - myapp-backend-php
    networks:
      - myapp-backend_network
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp-backend-nginx

  # PHP Service
  myapp-backend-php:
    build: ./.docker/php
    working_dir: /var/www/php
    #environment:
    #    DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/php
    depends_on:
      - myapp-backend-mysql
    networks:
      - myapp-backend_network
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp-backend-php

  # Mysql service
  myapp-backend-mysql:
    build: ./.docker/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
      - /storage/docker/myapp-backend-mysql-datadir:/var/lib/mysql

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    networks:
      - myapp-backend_network
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp-backend-mysql

networks:
  myapp-backend_network:
    driver: bridge
```

php dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    unzip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    jpegoptim \
    libicu-dev \ 
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    g++ \
    curl \
    python

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip mbstring simplexml dom

COPY config.aws /var/www/.aws/config
COPY credentials.aws /var/www/.aws/credentials

COPY xdebug.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
RUN pecl install xdebug redis
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis

# Install AWS-CLI
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py| python && \
    pip install awscli==1.16.100

#COPY config.aws /.aws/config
#COPY credentials.aws /.aws/credentials

RUN mkdir /var/company
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/company/
```

xdebug.ini

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.mode = debug,profile
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

So if you are using Docker I would recommend you to check your environment for issues or try switching to something else. Either WSL or maybe something like Xampp or Laragon just for quick testing purposes. So you can know that it is your environment that is the problem.

UPDATE 2022/03/01:1200 - I have migrated to our new WSL environment and xdebug + phpdebug works for two other dev's in vscode. But still not for me, I have also reinstalled vscode, removed all extensions (total reset) but still no luck.

Must be something with my PC.

<del>OLD:</del>

FYI - The problem is probably Docker / Docker Desktop, I tried looking into downgrading but firstly you would have to go back in version quite far and below 4 is not listed anymore on the website.

I know this because we confirmed XDebug makes a connection with vscode but then appears to break somewhere along the way. A colleague has tried a pure WSL setup without the docker(desktop) layer and got it working there.

Sadly I have not been able to figure out the exact issue but will update this post when I migrate over to our new WSL environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode IDE, than check your port in launch.json file. keep it 9000 and restart your vscode.

you can copy launch.json file from here.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9000,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Mh not sure what you mean by this, my launch.json used to work. I tried some combining some of your settings into mine but I don't use built-in and don't think current open script will work either. The "Listen for Xdebug" config needs my path mapping to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's beause the zend.extension line in your xdebug.ini isn't a full path.

Try re-downloading xdebug.
Then set your xdebug.ini like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

As you can see you probably need to set full path in zend_extension. (put any other configuration you need for docker, also useport 9000)

Then set your launch.json like this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Listen for XDebug",
          "type": "php",
          "request": "launch",
          "port": 9000,
      },
      {
          "name": "Launch currently open script",
          "type": "php",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${file}",
          "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
          "port": 9000
      }
  ]
}
```

**Important**
try `sudo apt-get install php7.2-xdebug` instead of the tar the wizzard suggests you and then follow the next steps from the wizzard.

Comment: I already checked the zend_extension xdebug.so path to make sure it was the right one by going into the docker image and then searching for it with "locate xdebug.so"
I added your options to my .ini but it didn't stop at the breakpoint yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that is a memory problem. Can you try to reduce `max_...` parameters, with something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/backend": "${workspaceRoot}",
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "resolved_breakpoints": "0",
                "max_data": 65536,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            },
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this post there is the same error: [Getting Xdebug to work properly with Docker and PhpStorm (it connects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291755/getting-xdebug-to-work-properly-with-docker-and-phpstorm-it-connects) on lines mismatch and it appears to be a memory problem.

Comment: Didn't do much for me sadly.